# Create a List using Index, Match, and Concatenate

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation

I have a formula in Excel, which is almost working. However, there is a part of the formula which no matter, what I try and do I can't seem to get it to work.

**Working Formula**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(DDRT!$K$7:$K$158,SMALL(IF(DDRT!$K$7:$K$158<>"",MATCH(ROW(DDRT!$K$7:$K$158),ROW(DDRT!$K$7:$K$158)),""),ROW(A1))),"")
```

This formula will create a list and ignore any blanks in the Array K7 to K158, which is exactly what I am trying to do, however, it is the `Value K` that is a variable and is based on a list in another sheet.

I have a concatenate which returns the correct value based on the list, which works fine.

**Concatenate Formula**

```
=CONCATENATE("DDRT!",ADDRESS(List!$E$6,MATCH(Transmittal!$D$3,DDRT!$A$6:$L$6,0)),":",ADDRESS(List!$E$7,MATCH(Transmittal!$D$3,DDRT!$A$6:$L$6,0)))
```

Value Returned - DDRT!$K$7:$K$158

When I try and combine the two formulas together, the array doesn't work and returns an error:

**Non-working formula**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(CONCATENATE("DDRT!",ADDRESS(List!$E$6,MATCH(Transmittal!$D$3,DDRT!$A$6:$L$6,0)),":",ADDRESS(List!$E$7,MATCH(Transmittal!$D$3,DDRT!$A$6:$L$6,0))),SMALL(IF(CONCATENATE("DDRT!",ADDRESS(List!$E$6,MATCH(Transmittal!$D$3,DDRT!$A$6:$L$6,0)),":",ADDRESS(List!$E$7,MATCH(Transmittal!$D$3,DDRT!$A$6:$L$6,0)))<>"",MATCH(ROW(CONCATENATE("DDRT!",ADDRESS(List!$E$6,MATCH(Transmittal!$D$3,DDRT!$A$6:$L$6,0)),":",ADDRESS(List!$E$7,MATCH(Transmittal!$D$3,DDRT!$A$6:$L$6,0)))),ROW(CONCATENATE("DDRT!",ADDRESS(List!$E$6,MATCH(Transmittal!$D$3,DDRT!$A$6:$L$6,0)),":",ADDRESS(List!$E$7,MATCH(Transmittal!$D$3,DDRT!$A$6:$L$6,0))))),""),ROW(A1))),"")
```

[Image of Returned Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2e7f.jpg)

Comment: yeah, got the same error when I entered it doing direct substitution for all the K7:K158 values.  On another note, your concatenate formula is returning a string of the address you want to use, but your working/nonworking formula is trying to use it as an address which does not fly.  I believe you will need to make use of INDIRECT formula to convert your string to a cell address that excel can use.  Which may bring about other issues depending n how many times the formula gets used.

Answer (score 2):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(ADDRESS($E$6,MATCH($D$3,$A$6:$L$6,0)),":",ADDRESS($E$7,MATCH($D$3,$A$6:$L$6,0)))),SMALL(IF(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(ADDRESS($E$6,MATCH($D$3,$A$6:$L$6,0)),":",ADDRESS($E$7,MATCH($D$3,$A$6:$L$6,0))))<>"",MATCH(ROW(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(ADDRESS($E$6,MATCH($D$3,$A$6:$L$6,0)),":",ADDRESS($E$7,MATCH($D$3,$A$6:$L$6,0))))),ROW(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(ADDRESS($E$6,MATCH($D$3,$A$6:$L$6,0)),":",ADDRESS($E$7,MATCH($D$3,$A$6:$L$6,0)))))),""),ROW(A1))),"")
```

That is your formula with indirect in it.  I had to remove sheet names so I could enter it in excel.  It does not have your error message.  All I did was wrap your concatenate formula in an indirect formula.

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("DDRT!",ADDRESS(List!$E$6,MATCH(Transmittal!$D$3,DDRT!$A$6:$L$6,0)),":",ADDRESS(List!$E$7,MATCH(Transmittal!$D$3,DDRT!$A$6:$L$6,0))))
```

Comment: Works a treat. Thanks Ed

Comment: @Forward Ed Really clever intelligent approach.